# Running process in the background at bootup different behaviour then manual start

Tags: bash, rc

I am trying to run `airodump` in the background.. I wrote the following script thats called from `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/sbin/airmon-ng check kill >> /tmp/airmon-kill 2>&1
sleep 2
/usr/local/sbin/airmon-ng start wlan0  > /tmp/airmon-start 2>&1
sleep 2
/usr/local/sbin/airodump-ng wlan0mon --manufacturer --uptime --wps --output-format csv --write-interval 5 --write log  > /tmp/airmon-dump 2>&1&
```

When I run these commands as root from the terminal they work fine. When I run them from `rc.local` I get all kind of issues..

First the kill script.. this one seems to work fine since the output is:

```
Killing these processes:

  PID Name
 2294 dhcpcd
```

Next the start script... thats where I get an error that I don't get when I run it on the terminal myself:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    mon.wlan0   rt2800usb   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370
phy0    wlan0       rt2800usb   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370

Error setting channel: command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
Error -16 likely means your card was set back to station mode by something.
Removing non-monitor mon.wlan0 interface...

WARNING: unable to start monitor mode, please run "airmon-ng check kill"
```

Any ideas why the behaviour is so different? Both run as root (I checked that) and both run from bash. Why the different behaviour?

Comment: What Linux distro is this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in `rc.local`, which, it appears to me, may run before networking is actually started, edit `/etc/network/interfaces`. Inside the definition for `wlan0` (or whatever your wireless interface is named), add a `post-up` command:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    ...
    post-up /path/to/your/bash/script.sh
```

This will run your script after the `wlan0` interface actually comes online.